# Gradle Composite Build, transitive dependency is not resolved

Tags: gradle, dependencies, repository, composite

First off, I'm sorry I have to showcase the problem in pseudocode, because the original library code is closed source and the overall build process is a little more complicated.

The Problem is as follows:

We have a project A, which uses an inhouse library B. This Library uses several opensource libraries, we call them C and D for now.

For debugging purposes I want to create a **gradle composite build** of project A, which includes library B using, `includeBuild`.

Project A: settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'A'

includeBuild '../B'
```

And Project A includes Library B in its build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
       compile group: 'bgroup', name: 'b', version: '1.0' 
}
```

Library B has C and D as dependencies. D has a own repository, C is on MavenCentral.

Library B build.gradle:

```
repositories {

  maven {
    url "http://D-Repository/maven"
  }

  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
       compile group: 'dgroup', name: 'd', version: '1.0'
       compile group: 'cgroup', name: 'c', version: '1.6'
}
```

I can compile Library B using its build.gradle file without a problem.
But when I try to compile the composite build of Project A, it says it:

> Could not find dgroup:d:1.0

I does resolve library C, **but not D**. I have to add the repository of D to the build.gradle file of Project A to make it work.

Project A including repository of D build.gradle:

```
repositories {
     maven {
       url "http://D-Repository/maven"
     }

     mavenCentral()
 }

 dependencies {
       compile group: 'bgroup', name: 'b', version: '1.0' 
 }
```

So I have to add the repository of D, even though A does not use it as a dependency directly.

- Is this expected behaviour?
- Am I missing a some configuration?

If I just get library B from our own repository (no composite build), I dont have to add the repository of D to project A. But this way I cannot debug B while working on project A.

Comment: library B on your repository, what does it has as dependencies in its metadata? Doesn't it also has D in its metadata? If not, why not, if yes, where does A take it from when using B from the repository?

Comment: Hi, thank you. You lead me in the right direction. Library B on the repository is build using a fatJar task instead of the normal jar task on our CI. This fatJar includes the missing transitive libraries to its meta. Now I have to find out if its possible to include the missing libs with the "includeBuild" composite build syntax somehow. If its not possible I will have to add the dependencies to the ProjectA.

Comment: Well, the dependency IS there with includeBuild, A just does not find it because it is in none of the repositories it knows. Btw. fatJars stink, especially for usage as dependency. For managing transitive dependencies you use a proper build tool like Gradle, Ant/Ivy or Maven.

Comment: So, is the cleanest way is to omit the fatJar task and add the missing repositories to the ProjectA build.gradle, even though it does not list them as dependency ?

Comment: Why should you add them as dependencies to A? They are dependencies of B. They are pulled in transitively automatically if you properly publish B with correct meta-data. That is the sense of a dependency managing build system. Also imagine you have A which depends on E version 1 and B which depends on E version 10, you build a fat jar of both and then you build C which depends on A and B. Now you will need twice the size as E is included twice, you don't know which one is actually used and so on. A proper build system will choose one version and include it in A or warn you about the conflict.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the clarification and help. You can write an short answer referencing the comments if you want, otherwise I will answer myself and mention you, in order to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found out in the comments, your published B is a fat JAR that contains the dependency classes. If you use the composite build, the normal transitive dependency resolution is used how it is meant. Using fat JARs as dependencies is very bad practice.

If you now depend on the composite build replacement of the fat JAR, you have proper dependency declarations, but A cannot find D, as it is not found in any repositories it knows of. You either have to make the dependency on B be replaced by the fat JAR from the included build, or switch to use proper transitive dependency handling how it is meant. This would involve publishing the normal B JAR, but with correct metadata that declares its dependencies and adding the D-specific repository to A, so that it can resolve the transitive dependency.

Comment: It also helps to use the `api` and `implementation` dependency type definitions. When a dependency is declared as `api 'com.group:artifact:+'` in project B, for example, project A should pick it up as a required dependency. This also requires using `apply plugin: 'java-library'` in the build file.